# Returning ActionResult without unpackaging a Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I often encounter this scenario where I have my services returning Tasks that I have to unpack before I return an `ActionResult` out of the controller.

```cs
public Task<ActionResult<Foo>> Action(int id)
{
    // Task<Foo> cannot be casted to Task<ActionResult<Foo>>
    return _fooService.Details(id); 
}
```

The task returned by the service cannot be implicitly cast to `ActionResult<Foo>`, so I end up unpacking the task in the controller. Like so,

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> Action(int id)
{
    return await _fooService.Details(id);
    // Both work
    return BadRequest();
}
```

If I don't wrap it in ActionResult, I can pass the task through but I cannot return other types of `IActionResults`.

```cs
public Task<Foo> Action(int id)
{
    return _fooService.Details(id); // <--- pass-through Task

    return BadRequest() // <-- But, I can't do this
}
```

My question is, is there a way to setup a conversion from a `Task<T>` to an `ActionResult<T>` without making the action async, perhaps through an implicit operator?

Comment: Convert the other direction: do `return Task.FromResult(BadRequest())`

Comment: @nlawalker But `BadRequest()` is not type `Foo`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. You could do it as an extension method: `public static async Task<ActionResult<T>> AsActionResult<T>(this Task<T> task) => await task;`. Then do `return _fooService.Details(id).AsActionResult();`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to mention **async** before Task

```
public async Task<Foo> Action(int id)
{
    return _fooService.Details(id); // <--- pass-through Task
    
    return BadRequest() // <-- Now it will run
}
```

Comment: That's wasting time with an `async` wrapper. There's no actual `async` code here; it is just returning a `Task<T>`. Your method is also not returning a `Task<ActionResult<T>>`